# Property of a differentiable function satisfying $(f(x))^{n} = f(nx)$ for all $x \in R$

Tags: calculus

Let $(f(x))^{n} = f(nx)$ be a differentiable function for all $x \in R$ then $f'(x)f(nx)= f(x)f'(nx)$
(True/false)

The statement is given to be true with a proof.

The function $e^{x}$ also satisfy this property, but $e^{x} e^{nx} ≠ e^{x}(ne^{nx})$

How can the statement be true$?$

Comment: Surely $e^xe^{nx}=e^xe^{nx}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have "$(f(x))^{n} = f(nx)$ is a differentiable function for all $x \in \mathbb R$"

Now I'll assume that this means something along the lines of "for some $n \ne 0$" (this is because if $n = 0$, we get no information about the derivative, and the formula certainly isn't true - see if you can find an example). It should work just as well if it is true for all $n$ in some domain.

You can start by differentiating both sides:
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left((f(x))^n\right)
  &= nf'(x)(f(x))^{n - 1} \\
 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(f(nx)\right)
  &= nf'(nx)
\end{align*}
But by we can use the original property of $f$, by multiplying both sides by $f(x)$:
\begin{align*}
 nf'(x)(f(x))^n &= nf'(nx)f(x) \\
 \implies f'(x)f(nx) &= f'(nx) f(x)
\end{align*}
as required.

Where you went wrong was in applying the formula. "$f'(nx)$" doesn't mean
"$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(f(nx))$", it means
"$\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}\vert_{nx}$", which is to say you calculate the derivative of *f* with respect to $x$ and plug in $nx$.

So in your case $f'(nx) = e^{nx}$, and the formula holds.